# Create an HTML/CSS/PHP frame with tabs, with seperate tab images

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I have a page set up with a large block in the middle, where I plan to display data relevant to the category selected from the tabs. I would like this data to auto-populate and paginate based on how many instances of relevant data there is.

I would also like to set it up so that when you have a tab selected, the background image blends into the large block, whereas the unselected tabs have graphics that clearly arent a piece of the same block.

I have the artwork all created, my html template ready to go, I just happen to be out of the loop programming wise by about 4-6 years. So I'm a bit lost on how to:

A) Create the relevant data stream, and format it.

B) Have the tabs reflect which category is selected.

I have this for the tab section in code:

```
<tr>
    <td background="images/LeftSideSpacer3.png" width="20" height="32"></td>
    <td background="images/LeftSideButtonSpacer.png" width="14" height="32"></td>
    <td background="images/LeftSideButtonSpacer2.png" width="2" height="32"></td>
    <td background="<?php tabStatus(); ?>" width="65" height="32">
        <a href="<?php $href=$CategoryTitle; ?>?<?php echo $href; ?>" name="<?php $SectionName='Hunter'; ?>Hunter" onClick="<?php $CategoryTitle='Hunter'; ?>">Hunter</a>
    </td>
    <td background="images/ButtonSpacer.png" width="3" height="32"></td>
    <td background="images/TabOff.png" width="65" height="32"></td>
```

Where `tabStatus()` calls a predefined function in my header:

```
function tabStatus() {
    if ($SectionName == $CategoryTitle) {
        return "images/TabOn.png";
    }
    else {
        return "images/TabOff.png";
    }
}
```

None of this works, which brings me back to being lost. And 4 hours googling and searching hasnt helped me much.

Comment: You might want to do stuff like tabstatus on the clientside in javascript instead. That's more conventional and will make your code more generic and easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not at all familiar with javascript, and not sure how I would define that function, is it possible for you to direct me towards a resource that could walk me through the process?

Comment: What kind of data do you want to load from the server? Plain HTML pages? Or images?

Comment: Essentially what I'm doing is loading a tabular list of members (data includes a portrait, name, title etc) that fills out set boxes with these data pieces, organized by 4 units/members per row, auto populating a next row when the first row hits 4 units.

Comment: Ah, that makes things a bit more clear. I think loading the content dynamically using javascript might be a bit overkill in this case, but it depends on the rest of the site. Assuming the data you are loading is the main content of your page, PHP only will do. I'll try to formulate an answer.

Comment: Thank you! I managed, through a moment of random inspiration, while I was trying to sleep ofcourse, a method of PDO calling to display the data as one unit, wrapped in a while() loop while there was data to display.. I topped that with a if($columnNumber == 5) statement to auto insert the end of that row and  start a new one. It worked out pretty well for me so far, but I definitely could use another perspective to try and clean it up a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you fetch your data from an sql database or anything similar.
In that case you can just iterate over the object containing your data and print it in a HTML context, like:

```
foreach($data as $value)
{
    // This is supposed to be the resulting HTML string for every data value
    echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>"; 
}
```

This will result in a static HTML page containing your data. With every client request a new page will be constructed, depending on the request.

In case you want a more dynamic approach, loading data into your site afterwards, have a look here
http://verido.dk/index.php/ressourcer/artikler/loading-and-saving-data-dynamically-using-php-jquery-and-mysql/

If you have any further problems, please be specific in your question. That will result in better answers. If you need general help with your programming stuff, you can better ask it on a forum (instead of StackExchange).

Answer (score 0):

You’re building an user interface, and you need to break it down into more manageable chunks. As it is, this question is hard to answer as there is no one “true” question nor one true answer.

Looking at the code provided, I’d suggest reading up on HTML and CSS. [HTML Dog](http://htmldog.com) is a good side to get started with creating semantic mark-up. From there, you can use your new-found skills to apply to your scenario. Dissecting other well-built web pages is also a good way to improve your HTML and CSS knowledge.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by "building a user interface", essentially, I'm building a dynamic content browsers, which will pull server data and format it. The formatting is going to be the hard part for me. Below that is a reactive tabular display, that does 2 things: 1) dictates the category for the dynamic content browser, and 2) visually displays its selection ( a simple image swap)

Comment: If you’re building something for a user to interact with, even if that interaction is just displaying content, then it’s a user interface. An UI could be crafted in HTML, CSS, Flash or many other ways.